# Git commits not showing on repo that I forked

Tags: github, git-branch, git-commit, git-fork

So, my friend made a repository, made me a collaborator, I branched out, forked and then cloned into my IDE.
Everything went fine with that, did some small changes and then wanted to test commit and push.
Commits and push went to my friends repo, everything is fine there, but they are not showing on my fork. 
I'm doing it this way (hope it's not the wrong way) to practice these kind of things and I would like to have that project on my profile after I'm done.
Thanks.

Comment: First of all; you shouldn't change the original repo if you're forking it. That defeats the purpose of forking in the first place. The only reason you're forking a repo is that you want something that repo offers but want to add a new feature that the original repo owner might not want. Secondly, a fork is like a copy of a file; if you copy a file and update the original, that doesn't mean the copy now magically gonna have that change. https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [Github's docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo):

"A fork is a copy of a repository.."

A fork essentially creates a separate repo. If you were committing and pushing to your friend's repo, your forked copy has no idea about it unless you push them to your repo also, or merge your friend's repo into your fork.

Ideally, you should never push to the original repo (your friend's repo) at all. Commit and push to your own repo by changing the [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), and when you want your commits to reflect in the original, you should raise a [Pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests) (assuming you're using GitHub).

Comment: Pull Requests with required pull request reviews by at least 2 developers, and a possibly a code owner is even better.

Answer (score 0):

You cloned it into your IDE, so you are editing his repo directly. No longer forking.